# Spring Cloud Stream - @StremListener condition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp

According to documentation: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streamlistener_for_content_based_routing
I can route the incoming message to a handler based on a condition like below:

```
@EnableBinding(MySink.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public static class TestPojoWithAnnotatedArguments {

    @StreamListener(target = MySink.INPUT, condition = "headers['type']=='bogey'")
    public void receiveBogey(@Payload BogeyPojo bogeyPojo) {
       // handle the message
    }

    @StreamListener(target = MySink.INPUT, condition = "headers['type']=='bacall'")
    public void receiveBacall(@Payload BacallPojo bacallPojo) {
       // handle the message
    }

    @StreamListener(target = MySink.ANOTHER_INPUT, condition = "headers['type']=='bacall'")
    public void receiveBacall(@Payload BacallPojo bacallPojo) {
       // handle the message
    }
}
```

How do I provide a handler that's called when none of the conditions match?

If I have 2 handlers, first one with a condition and second one without any, both the handlers are called when the first one's condition matches. How do i avoid this?

Comment: It looks like this is not possible.

The handleRequestMessage(..) delivers to all matching handlers and has no default handler concept judging from the spring-cloud-stream source code:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binding/DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.java

Comment: Please don' t ask variation of the same question in two different places - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61188379/spring-cloud-stream-call-handler-based-on-payload-type-with-rabbitmq-binder/61188848?noredirect=1#comment108248848_61188848. It is taking away the time of people who contribute and confuses the readers when answers come.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that annotation-based model is all but deprecated. Please go through these 3 post to better understand the direction we're going. The last post also provides more details on content-based routing. https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/14/spring-cloud-stream-demystified-and-simplified, https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/17/spring-cloud-stream-functional-and-reactive, https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/31/spring-cloud-stream-event-routing

Comment: I went through the posts. I have multiple sources (similar to what i would have with target = Sink.INPUT, target = Sink.INPUT2, and so on), and each of those sources produce multiple type of messages. So, i want to be able to route based on some condition, specific to each source. I see only a generic property "spring.cloud.function.routing-expression" which will be applied to all sources. Also, what about the scenario of default handler?
It would be really great if you could point me to an example/test, as I am unable to find any.

Comment: I have modified my question with the code based on the multiple input types per source binding.

Answer (score 0):

We probably need to modify the section you're referring to as it is somewhat outdated.

Also, we can not (should not) do any kind of routing based on the payload type, since the data comes in from the wire in the serialised form such as `byte[]`. I discuss it in details in [this old post](https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/26/spring-cloud-stream-2-0-content-type-negotiation-and-transformation). 
But you can definitely use other parts of the incoming Message as routing condition. The recommended best practice is to rely on Message Headers.

So let's look at the sample:

```
@Bean
public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
    return v -> v.toUpperCase();
}

@Bean
public Function<String, String> lowercase() {
    return v -> v.toLowerCase();
}

@Bean
public Function<String, String> reverse() {
    return v -> new StringBuilder(v).reverse().toString();
}
```

. . .and indeed a single `routing-expression` property. You only need one expression, since however complex or simple your condition is it can be encoded with standard Spring SpEL

```
--spring.cloud.function.routing-expression=headers['type'] == 'upper' ? 'uppercase' : (headers['type'] == 'lower' ? 'lowercase' : ''reverse)
```

What will happen is, the incoming Message's header with the name `type` will be evaluated. And if its value is 'upper' it will go to 'uppercase' function; if 'lower' to 'lowercase' function and default to 'reverse'.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In this case, this condition is applied on messages coming to which binding? "input" ? or "spring.cloud.stream.bindings.uppercase-in-0.source" etc? Can you please provide details on this? Also, if I have multiple sources, the condition needs to be specific to each source, since one condition can be true for messages from 2 different sources, but may need different handlers. This will lead to modify routing function and add more conditions.

P.S i agree with you on using message headers for routing.

Comment: Also, how will this work when i have multiple sources? (eg. different queues bound to different exchanges). how will the naming of these Consumers work?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question about multiple sources; You have no idea about sources since you consume messages from bound destinations and the only variable you have to use for your condition is the Message itself and possibly binding properties. As for the binding, its from `functionRouter-in-0` and it is explained in this section - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_routing_to_consumer

Comment: What i mean is, for reading from a queue1 bound to exchange1, the binding properties would be:- spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumer1.source="exchange1";*.consumer1.group=queue1 and likewise for queue2/exchange2: spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumer2.source="exchange2"

How do i configure these properties for use with Functions? is it functionRouter-in-0  = exchange1 and functionRouter-in-1 =exchange2  ??

Comment: I am sorry, but have you actually read through documentation? I believe I have provided as much information as I could possibly do. I don't know what else I can say. On top of that SO discourages long "comment threads", so. . . Please write some code, follow the docs, there are samples there, and if/when you encounter a problem ask another more specific question relevant to the actual code you have written provided as a sample and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Sure. the example here provided finally helped me understand:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/multi-functions-samples/multi-functions-rabbit/src/main/java/demo/MultipleFunctionsApplication.java